# Multiple router-outlets in Angular 5 app (not named)

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I'm building an application that looks like this:
[image]

I need to render some components to the `<router-outlet>` in `ContainerOneComponent` by pressing the `TabComponent` (of `ContainerOneComponent`) and other components to the `<router-outlet>` of `ContainerTwoComponent` by pressing the `TabComponent` (of `ContainerTwoComponent`).
I don't want to use named router-outlets because I want to have standard routing in the url. e.g `some/state/of/my/app`.

I know it is possible to implement this with nested routes but it didn't worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact problem statement you want to solve, i am asking this because for just showing different content in tabs doesn't  need routing?

Comment: So, you say that tabs navigation doesn't need routing? What about modals or pop-ups?

Answer (score -1):

You must have only one unamed router outlet, can you attach any error/plunker?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. It just behaves strange. I saw some examples, but couldn't implement this.